# Quickest way to hide an array of pictureboxes

Tags: arrays, vb.net, winforms, list, foreach

I have an array of pictureboxes named from B11 (co-ords 1,1) to B55 (co-ords 5,5). I would like to hide these all on startup (and in the middle of running). I was thinking of making an array of the names manually but would it be the best solution?

Comment: Is this a WinForm desktop app?

Comment: @DourHighArch Yes this is WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they all have a common parent control, such as a panel or groupbox (or even the form):

```
Parent.SuspendLayout()
For Each pbox As PictureBox in Parent.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)()
   pbox.Visible = False
Next pbox
Parent.ResumeLayout()
```

The Suspend/Resume-Layout() is to avoid flickering as you modify a bunch of controls at once.

Comment: Assuming that `Parent` only contains picture boxes, you could just do `Parent.Visible=false`.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the PictureBox class and use event handling to accomplish this by:

- Adding a public property to the form to tell if the picture boxes should be shown or hidden.
- Adding an event to the form that is raised when the show/hide picture box property is changed.
- Extending the PictureBox class so that it subscribes to the event of the parent form.
- Setting the visible property of the extended PictureBox class to the show/hide property of the parent form.

When the show/hide flag is changed on the parent form all of the picture boxes will change their visibility property accordingly.

Form Code:

```
    public partial class PictureBoxForm : Form {
        public PictureBoxForm() {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.pictureBoxesAdd();
        }


        private void pictureBoxesAdd() {
            MyPictureBox mp1 = new MyPictureBox();
            mp1.Location = new Point(1, 1);         
            MyPictureBox mp2 = new MyPictureBox();
            mp2.Location = new Point(200, 1);
            this.Controls.Add(mp1);
            this.Controls.Add(mp2);
        }

        public event EventHandler PictureBoxShowFlagChanged;

        public bool PictureBoxShowFlag {
            get { return this.pictureBoxShowFlag; }
            set {
                if (this.pictureBoxShowFlag != value) {
                    pictureBoxShowFlag = value;
                    if (this.PictureBoxShowFlagChanged != null) {
                        this.PictureBoxShowFlagChanged(this, new EventArgs());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private bool pictureBoxShowFlag = true;

        private void cmdFlip_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
            this.PictureBoxShowFlag = !this.PictureBoxShowFlag;
        }
    }
```

Extended PictureBox Code:

```
    public class MyPictureBox : PictureBox {

        public MyPictureBox() : base() {
            this.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.ParentChanged += new EventHandler(MyPictureBox_ParentChanged);
        }

        private void MyPictureBox_ParentChanged( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
            try {
                PictureBoxForm pbf = (PictureBoxForm)this.Parent;
                this.Visible = pbf.PictureBoxShowFlag;
                pbf.PictureBoxShowFlagChanged += new
                    EventHandler(pbf_PictureBoxShowFlagChanged);
            } catch { }
    }

    private void pbf_PictureBoxShowFlagChanged( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
            PictureBoxForm pbf = (PictureBoxForm)sender;
            this.Visible = pbf.PictureBoxShowFlag;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

...or just put 'em all on a Panel, and change the panel's visibility.